# Aggregate logical AND / OR for columns with type 'bit'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, sql-server-2016

For the T-SQL (SQL Server 2016) `bit`  type, is there some way to achieve an aggregate equivalent of a logical AND and a logical OR? For example, with this table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Example       (id int, category int, isRed bit, isBlue bit)
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (     1,            1,         1,          1)
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (     2,            1,         0,          0)
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (     3,            1,         1,          0)
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (     4,            2,         0,          1)
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (     5,            2,         0,          1)
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (     6,            2,         0,          1)
```

I'd like to create a query that lists, per category, if *any* of `isRed` is set (OR), and if *all* of `isBlue` is set (AND), e.g. outputting:

```
category  anyRed  allBlue
       1       1        0
       2       0        1
```

That is, I'd *like* something like:

```
SELECT
  category,
  OR(isRed) isAnyRed,
  AND(isBlue) isAllBlue
FROM
  #Example
GROUP BY
  category
```

The only thing I could think of to try was:

```
SELECT
  category,
  MAX(isRed) isAnyRed,
  MIN(isBlue) isAllBlue
FROM
  #Example
GROUP BY
  category
```

Which does not work, giving the error:

```
Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.
```

Similar results occur with all other aggregate functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`MIN` and `MAX` functions can be used:

```
SELECT
  category,
  MAX(CONVERT(tinyint,isRed)) isAnyRed,
  MIN(CONVERT(tinyint,isBlue)) isAllBlue
FROM
  #Example
GROUP BY
  category
```

But you have to convert `bit` to some numeric value (`tinyint`), as `MIN` and `MAX` work only with numbers, not booleans.

Comment: @JasonC your solution with `MIN` and `MAX` is correct, the problem was in `CONVERT`. Glad to help!

Comment: this is much better than trying to add logarithms and dealing with zeros!

Answer (score 2):

You can use subquery and find as below:

```
Select Category, AnyRed = Case When SmRed > 0 then 1 else 0 End,
        AllBlue = Case When SmBlue = Cnt then 1 else 0 End from  (
    select category, SMRed = sum(iif(isred=1,1,0)), SMBlue = Sum(iif(isBlue=1,1,0)), Cnt= Count(id) from #Example
    group by category
) a
```